# How Do I Fix Trailing Slash Issue?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I add this line of code into my .htaccess file my site crashes. Here's the code:

```
# Force trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|xml|txt|js|php|scss|webp|mp3|avi|wav|mp4|mov)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

And here's the original .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to fix the trailing slash issue on my site.

Comment: Welcome to SO, regarding your statement `When I add this line of code into my .htaccess file my site crashes.` Do you have any other rules apart from shown ones? Also what errors you are seeing in Logs?

Comment: Hi there thank you very much for your reply. Here's my original .htaccess file:

Comment: ```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can edit your question to add new info (such as your .htaccess content) which will make things more easy to read. Also, are there any errors in logs that you can share?